# Is it better to use the link tag or the style tag to import CSS?

Tags: html, css, performance

Or is it just a personal preference thing? What I'm getting at is, is there a specific benefit to using either method?

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

versus

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url('main.css');
</style>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to Yahoo's [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), always use `<link>` instead of `@import`. More detailed information is available in [this blog post](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/).

> In IE (tested on 6, 7, and 8), `@import`
>   causes the stylesheets to be
>   downloaded sequentially. Downloading
>   resources in parallel is key to a
>   faster page. This behavior in IE
>   causes the page to take a longer time
>   to finish.

Using `<link>` allows the browser to open additional connections, thereby decreasing load times.

Comment: That answer makes more sense to me.

Comment: As well as this, Internet Explorer 5 and below will not parse a @import at all - which is what some older hacks would use to have extra rules defined

Answer (score 10):

Short version? `@import` is not supported in old browsers, in certain situation has problems with certain browsers in common use (IE6 **and** IE7), can behave differently in different browsers when it does work and offers no advantage over `<link>`.

Long version? You want to use `<link>` but there are a couple of scenarios (now mostly irrelevant) where using `@import` made sense. From [What's the Difference Between @import and link for CSS?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/f/css_import_link.htm):

> The most common reason given for using
>   @import instead (or along with) 
>   is because older browsers didn't
>   recognize @import, so you could hide
>   styles from them.

That's talking about hiding things from IE4, which is why I said "mostly irrelevant". One of those cases hides things from IE6 but that's better done with [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

A more modern (and relevant) comparison is in [Using the CSS @import Rule](http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/):

> nternet Explorer (you knew it’d come
>   up eventually) doesn’t deal well with
>   specifying media types – it chokes.
>   Basically, IE (versions 4-7) try to
>   read the media type like it were part
>   of the file name, causing the whole
>   thing to come crashing down. As such,
>   if you don’t want your CSS to have a
>   default media type of “all,” you’re
>   probably better off using a
>   combination of the  tag and
>   imports – specifying a media type in
>   your link, and then importing the
>   appropriate CSS within the file you’re
>   linking to. I haven’t yet heard if IE8
>   suffers from this same problem (if you
>   happen to know, please enlighten me in
>   the comments!).

Another source is Yahoo's [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html):

> One of the previous best practices
>   states that CSS should be at the top
>   in order to allow for progressive
>   rendering.
>
> In IE `@import` behaves the same as
>   using  at the bottom of the
>   page, so it's best not to use it.

but doesn't *really* explain why (hence the previous links).

Comment: In fact the problem occurs if I recall when you use more than one css file. Then, if you are using @import inside css files, you cause IE to download css files sequentially instead of in parallel when using the <link> tag. Downloading in parallel is faster as two or more files are downloading at once. More explanations here : http://stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Comment: You're correct there strager. If you're @import-ing and you omit the line breaks then both are exactly the same in terms of the size of the html document. You can make gains by doing a link or an @import and then @import-ing the rest of your css in your main.css document. Cletus, it looks as if you're partly correct in that @import causes the browser to download the CSS sequentially rather than in parallel in a separate request (See William Brendel's response). I don't think caching is actually an issue (anymore?)